# Can it be possible rendering multiple objects in one screen without creating shader in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

My course teacher taught me how to draw a figure e.g. square, triangle, circle. He did it using `glBegin` and `glEnd`. But when I try to draw multiple object for example **circle within a square**, I can't. After searching in online, I understood that `shader` is the thing that need to implement to draw or control how the objects will be rendered.

But as my course teacher didn't teach me `shader`, is there any possible way to do that using legacy OpenGL I mean with `glBegin` and `glEnd`?

I am using `Codeblocks` and `GLUT` to learn OpenGL. And the language I am using is `C++`.

The code I wrote to draw only circles and that worked:

```
#include<GL/gl.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

// Center of the cicle = (320, 240)
int xc = 320, yc = 240;

// Plot eight points using circle's symmetrical property
void plot_point(int x, int y)
{
  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  glVertex2i(xc+x, yc+y);
  glVertex2i(xc+x, yc-y);
  glVertex2i(xc+y, yc+x);
  glVertex2i(xc+y, yc-x);
  glVertex2i(xc-x, yc-y);
  glVertex2i(xc-y, yc-x);
  glVertex2i(xc-x, yc+y);
  glVertex2i(xc-y, yc+x);
  glEnd();
}

// Function to draw a circle using bresenham's
// circle drawing algorithm
void mid_point_circle(int r)
{
  int x=0,y=r;
  float pk=(5.0/4.0)-r;

  /* Plot the points */
  /* Plot the first point */
  plot_point(x,y);
  int k;
  /* Find all vertices till x=y */
  while(x < y)
  {
    x = x + 1;
    if(pk < 0)
      pk = pk + 2*x+1;
    else
    {
      y = y - 1;
      pk = pk + 2*(x - y) + 1;
    }
    plot_point(x,y);
  }
  glFlush();
}

// Function to draw two concentric circles
void concentric_circles(void)
{
  /* Clears buffers to preset values */
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  int radius1 = 100, radius2 = 200;
  mid_point_circle(radius1);
  mid_point_circle(radius2);
}

void Init()
{
  /* Set clear color to white */
  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0);
  /* Set fill color to black */
  glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
  /* glViewport(0 , 0 , 640 , 480); */
  /* glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); */
  /* glLoadIdentity(); */
  gluOrtho2D(0 , 640 , 0 , 480);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* Initialise GLUT library */
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  /* Set the initial display mode */
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  /* Set the initial window position and size */
  glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
  glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
  /* Create the window with title "Mid-point Circle" */
  glutCreateWindow("Mid-point Circle");
  /* Initialize drawing colors */
  Init();
  /* Call the displaying function */
  glutDisplayFunc(concentric_circles);
  /* Keep displaying untill the program is closed */
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rendering "multiple objects" doesn't depend on whether you're using a shader program or not. For multiple different objects, you need to make multiple draw calls or implement multiple `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences.
For each draw call or each `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences you must specify the   type of the [Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive):

```cpp
glBegin(GL_LINES);
// [...]
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
// [...]
glEnd();
```